# Converting 4 Byte float plain binary little endian format into plain text in C#?

Tags: c#, binary, endianness

I am very new in binary file handling in C#.

I have a 4 Byte float plain binary little endian format(.dat) data file. I want to write the data in a text file. Is it possible in C#?

I have tried some codes found from different sources. But I failed.

Anyone have any suggestion or reference or sample code? I want to do it in C# as I am familiar with it.

When I open my file in notepad,
The values looks like:

š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿š™¿  ,Á  ,Á  ,Á  ,Á  ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,ÁìQ,Á  ,Á  ,Á  ,Á  ,Á  ,Á  ,Á  ,Á  ,Á  ,Á

The codes that I have tried following.

```
        string inputFilename="F:\\nkg.0000.dat";
        string outputFilename = "F:\\test.txt";
        byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(inputFilename);

        int counter = fileBytes.Length;
        MessageBox.Show(counter.ToString());
        for (int k = 0; k < counter; k++)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(outputFilename, (fileBytes[k].ToString() + "\r\n"));
        }
```

It gives values like this:
205
204
76
192
205
204
76
192
205
204
76
192
205
204
76
192
205
204
76
192
205
204
76
192
205
204
76
192
205
204
76

The output contains 1000 values but it should contain 250 values. 
Again it seems that the values are not correct. But I do not know the actual values.

Comment: post the code that you've tried so far and the error that you got.  It will be much easier to help you then.

Comment: Dear paqogomez, I have edited my question to show code and its output.

Comment: Excellent, but rather than supply what the program has erronously output, post a sample of what the dat contains and what it should look like when converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
string inputFilename="F:\\nkg.0000.dat";
string outputFilename = "F:\\test.txt";
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(inputFilename);
int count = fileBytes.Length / 4;
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
for (int k = 0; k < count; k += 4) {
    float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(fileBytes, k);
    s.AppendLine(f.ToString());
}
File.AppendAllText(outputFilename, s.ToString());
```

Since you want the original float values, you have to convert the bytes into floats. The essential part is [`BitConverter.ToSingle(fileBytes, k)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which converts 4 bytes into a 32 bit float value.

Please note that the number of floats is only 1/4 of the byte count and `k` is increased by 4 (32 bit float = 4 bytes). The above code therefore returns the expected 250 floats.

*One more hint:*
Don't' use `File.AppendAllText` in the for loop - this opens, writes, and closes the file 250 times. Convert all floats to a string and append it to a `StringBuilder` and write it to file in a single call. This is much faster and uses much less resources.

Comment: Thanks a lot joe for your reply. I am trying to use the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using File.ReadAllBytes to read your data, you're getting back an array of bytes, as opposed to an array of floats which is what you say your data file contains.  That also explains why you're getting 1000 values instead of the 250 you expect (since a float is four bytes).

Take a look at BitConverter.ToSingle ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to convert the byte values you got to floats.